# main.cs(7,5): error CS0103: The name `watch' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine(watch);
  }
  public static int Number (int num) {
    watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    Console.ReadLine();
    watch.Stop();
    return watch;
  }
}
```

I am having a problem were watch does not exist in the current context. This might be a easy problem to fix but i am new to c# so idk the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You aren't declaring the `watch` variable at all, and you can't reference a variable in one method from another.  Variable scope.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your code like below

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetElapsedTime());
    }
    public static long GetElapsedTime()
    {
        // You have to specify your variable like below
        // for more information : https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_variables.asp
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        watch.Stop();
        return watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }
}
```

I changed your method "Number" to "GetElapsedTime" because it was not a suitable name.

I think your purpose was to return the elapsed time, I fixed the code.
for more information use link below:

https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_variables.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_methods.asp
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: ohh when typed the code in i removed the var in front of watch. and that dident work so thanks so much!

Answer (score -2):

In order to use a variable in multiple methods. You need to declare it in the `global scope`.

**Example:**

```
class MainClass{
    public static Stopwatch watch;
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        watch = new Stopwatch();
        Watch_Start();
        Watch_Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }

    public static void Watch_Start(){
        watch.Start();
    }

    public static void Watch_Stop(){
        watch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: class scope != global scope, and teaching people to place variables in a global scope isn't good practice.  You've also made unnecessary alterations to the flow of their code.  The original code calculated the amount of time it took the user to enter some text.  That is gone.  Why?

Comment: Also, this code won't run.  You aren't instantiating `watch` anywhere.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Amy The reason why the code is different is because I don't want to just solve the problem for them. I crafted an example to allow them to try things out for themselves, allowing for a better learning process. You are right that the code will not run, I forgot to instantiate it, and you are also right about the global scope thing, I am too used to js